# Is it better to pre-filter the entire data set or just the training sub-set?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, dataset

I am currently working on a classifier for the qualitative spectral analysis of alloys.

One of the problems that I faced is preparation of samples for the classifier training. Samples have to me machined into chips that can physically fit into the spectrometer's sample chamber.

During cross-validation I have noticed a few very peculiar miss-classifications that simply should not happen (the elemental composition is too different), esp. taking into consideration the overall performance of the classifier. Upon careful examination I found something that looks like contaminated (or possible mislabeled, although this is very unlikely) sample. Anomaly detector confirms that and makes it very simple to find such samples and remove them.

My question is, what would considered the a better practice in the machine learning:

- Filter entire data set so neither training nor cross-validation data has any outliers.
- Filter only the training set and leave outliers in the cross-validation set.

Real world samples for which this classifier is prepared are unlikely to have this sort of contamination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pretty much answered your question with that last sentence. Assuming you are building a model to be used in a real world application, you want its training and evaluation setup to be as close as possible to said application.

If you have no outliers in reality, then get rid of them in your own data set too. Having no outliers in a real world application sounds too good to be true, though, so be sure about that or you will be way too optimistic about the model's performance.

Comment: So a prudent measure would be to remove outliers from the training set and keep them in the cross validation set to have a better measure of the classifier performance?

Comment: Also, I would never say that the real world would not have outliers, it just going to be a different kind of outliers since the metal chips would be a wear debris and not machined chips.

Comment: @udushu if those outliers are not present in the real world data, then you shouldn't have them in the test set. You always want to maximize the similarity of how you evaluate the model and how it is actually going to be used.

Comment: ... however, it may be worth while to put the outliers into a separate set (they haven't been used for training so you can have them as separate outlier test set) so you can nevertheless check the performance for them. I agree with Marc that you do *not* want to mix them into the "normal" test results. I sometimes do this to check the robustness of  Raman spectroscopic classifiers against spikes.